# Have a Database that i got from an Iphone project (.sqlite)

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the change that i need to do to implement an Iphone Database (.sqlite) to my android project?

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you wish to create a similar database in Android from ground up or just want to import it in your Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android comes with SQLite3, you can either create your database from ground up or you can ship your application with a pre-populated database.

The following might prove useful:
1. [SQLite Basics](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)
2. [Ship Android application with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)
3. [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

Android also uses SQLite, so same DB should work.

Comment: I have just copy .sqlite file from the iphone to android assets folder and use that database in my android app. But it get crashed.